# Anonymous callback functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, return-value

So, I understand callback functions to a degree. For instance, I completely understand this:

```
function finalGuy(x) {
    alert("Final Number: " + x);
}

function secondGuy(x, callback) {
    x = x - Math.sqrt(x);
    callback(x);
}

function firstGuy(callback) {
    var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"));
    x *= x;
    secondGuy(x, callback);
}


firstGuy(finalGuy);
```

However, when faced with something like this I can't seem to grasp it.

```
a(function () {
    b(function () {
        c()
    })
});
```

Can someone please translate the first sequence of callbacks into a working example like the second one? Specifically, passing one result to the next callback similarly to how I did it in the first example.

Comment: please add the wanted outcome.

Comment: @NinaScholz I wanted the second block's outcome to mimic the first block's outcome, or something similar.

Comment: It's hard to tell that that code means without knowing the `a`, `b` and `c` functions.

Comment: "callbacks of this nature" it is the same thing but with anonymous functions. The fact that they are callbacks doesn't change

Comment: @Daniel_L I understand that they are the same thing, and I do understand anonymous functions somewhat. I can't seem to pass a value from a(), to b(), to c()

Comment: but you have only a and b, not c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two produce the same result

**1.**

```
function acceptCallback(callback) {
  callback();
}

function callback() {
  console.log('callback invoked');
}

acceptCallback(callback); // => 'callback invoked'
```

**2.**

```
function acceptCallback(callback) {
  callback();
}

acceptCallback(function() {
  console.log('callback invoked');
});
```

In the first example you pass a function declaration, in the second example you pass an anonymous function

**3. Performing operations in the scope of a callback to be passed to another callback, aka "callback hell"**

Nothing special here, it's the same syntax as the first two examples. This is difficult to read for anyone.

```
function first(callback) {
  callback('from first');
}

function second(callback) {
  callback('from second');
}

function third(callback) {
  callback('from third');
}

function fourth(n, callback) {
  callback(n * 10);
}

first(function(fromFirst) {
  var a = 5;
  console.log(fromFirst); // 'from first'
  second(function(fromSecond) {
    console.log(fromSecond); // 'from second'
    third(function(fromThird) {
      console.log(fromThird); // 'from third'
      var b = a + 5; // 10
      fourth(b, function(fromFouth) {
        console.log(a, b, fromFourth); // 5, 10, 100
      })
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: So how would I properly pass a result from one anonymous function to a second anonymous function? I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but when I try to use anonymous functions for the same operation as in my original block, i either get undefined, NaN, or it just alerts my function.

Comment: For instance, in my first example I have a function that does some operations on a number, passes it to the second function which does some more operations on it, passes it to the third which displays it. Can you modify your example with the anonymous functions to show how I can do this?

Comment: @GD added another example. generally, you want to avoid writing code like that anyway. do a search for "callback hell" to see why.